# How to create a flip-open navbar?

Tags: wordpress, navbar

I'm trying to create a navbar that looks like this wordpress [theme](http://ximudesign.com/za3/). I'm still very new to the industry and only have HTML/CSS experience. So I am open to ALL types of recommendations/demos/research places. Anything to help me build that menu structure! Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I advise you to review the [help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) on how to ask proper questions in order to get more help and better answers.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using JQuery functions such as... 
$('#something').click(function() {} .removeClass('') .addClass('') 
..to toggle css visibility: or display: attributes in order to switch between showing or hiding the navbar links.

Once done JQuery functions such as...
$( "#something" ).fadeOut( "fast" , function() {$('#something').removeClass('activa');};
...would take care of the transitions. Some transitions can be handled using only css too.
Hope this helps you!